# Scheduled job on Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell, scheduled-tasks, azure-webjobs, azure-automation

We are developing an application that is going to be hosted on Azure as a web application with a SQL Server database.

We need to run a scheduled job on the SQL Server every day that updates dates with one day in the database for a demo environment. When we host the application outside of Azure, we had a SQL Server agent job that executed the following SQL query every day.

```
update Document set Uploaded = dateadd(day, 1, Uploaded)
update UserAction set DateTime = dateadd(day, 1, DateTime)
update DrainingService set NextDrainingDate = dateadd(day, 1, NextDrainingDate)
update DrainingService set PerformedDate = dateadd(day, 1, PerformedDate)
update DrainingServiceSheet set DrainingDate = dateadd(day, 1, DrainingDate)
update Inventory set InventoryDate = dateadd(day, 1, InventoryDate)
update Inspection set NextInspectionDate = dateadd(day, 1, NextInspectionDate)
update Inspection set PerformedDate = dateadd(day, 1, PerformedDate)
update InspectionSheet set InspectionDate = dateadd(day, 1, InspectionDate)
update Note set DateTime = dateadd(day, 1, DateTime)
```

As SQL Server Agent doesn't exist on Azure, we need to run something similar with either Azure automation, web job or anything that solves the problem.

What is the best solution for this, and how do you create a PowerShell script that executes the same SQL query as the one above if we go with Azure automation?

Comment: Here's some samples: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-use-a-SQL-Command-be77f9d2 and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/ . In short you need to give the Azure Automation account access to your database. Then you can schedule some standard powershell script to connect to the database and run a stored procedure. Then just put all that update code into the stored procedure. You should start by reading up on Azure Automation and Runbooks